# Stucked with Yii Framework Form tutorial

Tags: php, forms, yii

I keep on reading this tutorial of Yii framework over and over again
[Yii Framework - Working with Form](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.overview)

I already created my Model with this following codes

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = false;

    private $_identity;

    public function rules(){
        return array(
            /* array(<field>,<field>,<function to invoke>)
            * functions required and boolean are built-in validators of the yii framework.
            * you can invoke your own function by defining your own function
            */
            array('username','password','required'),
            array('rememberMe','boolean'),
            array('password','authenticate'),
        );
    }

    public function authenticate(){
        $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        if(!$this->_identity->authenticate()){
            $this->addError("password","Incorrect Username or Password");
        }
    }

    public function attributeLabels(){
        return array(
            'username'=>"Username",
            'password'=>"Password",
            'rememberMe'=>"Remember Me",
        );
    }
}
```

and my Action function with this codes in my controller

```
 public function actionLogin(){
        //calls the Login Model that will be used in this action
        $model = new LoginForm;
        if(isset($_POST["LoginForm"])){
            //collects user input
            $model->attributes = $_POST["LoginForm"];
            //validates user input using the model rules and redirects back to
            //previous page when user input is invalid
            if($model->validate()){
               $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);   
            }
            //redisplay the login form
            $this->render('login',array('loginModel'=>$model));
        }
    }
```

and lastly in my View

```
<div class="form">
<?php
    $formlogin = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm');     
    echo $formlogin->errorSummary($model);
?>
       <div class="row">
       <?php
            $formlogin->label($model,'username');
            $formlogin->textField($model,'username');
       ?>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
       <?php
            $formlogin->label($model,'password');
            $formlogin->passwordField($model,'password');
       ?>
       </div>
       <div class="row rememberMe">
       <?php
            $formlogin->checkBox($model,'rememberMe');
            $formlogin->label($model,'rememberMe');
       ?>
       </div>
       <div class="row submit">
       <?php
            echo CHtml::submitButton('Login');
       ?>
       </div>
<?php 
$this->endWidget();
?>
</div>
```

and i always came out with this error in my view
D:\xampp\htdocs\wiltalk\protected\views\sandbox\index.php(11)

> Undefined variable: model

do i miss something? please let me know... I know this is kinda simple but I am a first-timer in using such component-based MVC frameworks.... Thanks

Comment: change this - 
$this->render('login',array('loginModel'=>$model));
to this - 
$this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function actionLogin(){
        //calls the Login Model that will be used in this action
        $model = new LoginForm;
        if(isset($_POST["LoginForm"])){
            //collects user input
            $model->attributes = $_POST["LoginForm"];
            //validates user input using the model rules and redirects back to
            //previous page when user input is invalid
            if($model->validate()){
               $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);   
            }            
        }
        //redisplay the login form
        $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
    }
```

Your code was not correct.
Make these changes to your code.

1. You are using model variable and passing loginModel variable.
2. You are rendering view file on POST.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a shot in the dark...
For your controller `public function actionLogin(){` add `return $model;` at the end.
Add `<?php $model = actionLogin(); ?>` to the top of your view.
The issue is that you're not setting `$model` anywhere in your view, but your control is setting it. You must find some way to pass that `$model` that's being set in your control back your your view.

Comment: return an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function actionLogin() in D:\xampp\htdocs\wiltalk\protected\views\sandbox\index.php on line 10"

Comment: look at this tutorial... i don't see any variable "$model" was passed in the view http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.view

Comment: I already got it sir ^_^ there is no problem in the model... but in the controller... i was not able to pass the model instance to the view using my controller thanks anyways ^_^